# Online mp4 video is not playing

Tags: android, android-video-player

what's the problem there, I have uploaded this video to server, but now its not playing, but its playing if i put this video on sdcard which is commented

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


        private MediaController mc;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        VideoView vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

        mc = new MediaController(this);
        vd.setMediaController(mc);
Toast.makeText(this, "Video Player Started", 20).show();
          //vd.setVideoPath("sdcard/video/abc.mp4");
        vd.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.primesquad.com/future.mp4"));

        vd.start();
        }

        }
```

Comment: Just making sure, do you have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> ?

Comment: What's the codec used to save the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

streaming video differ from playing it from sdCard as you see in [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) there is restrictions for streaming that don't apply when playing video.
I faced this problem with videos stream normally in HTC Desire but refuse to stream with Motorola droid